# Diagonal Screen Tearing Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics

Tags: 14.04, graphics, ati, intel, tearing

For quite a some time now I'm having a bit of trouble with diagonal screen tearing. So, from the top of the right side of the screen, it goes diagonally to the bottom left side of the screen. Now, the upper half of that diagonal doesn't get teared at all, but, the tearing always occurs in the lower half of that diagonal.

Hopefully someone has some solution to this problem.

The Specs:

Processor: Intel Core i5-6200 CPU @ 2.30GHz x 4

Integrated ( and main ) Graphics: Intel Skylake ULT GT2

Memory: 8 GiB

OS type: 64-bit

*( unused ) Graphics: AMD Radeon R5 M335 4GB DDR3

p.s. Should also mention that I'm using Linux Kernel 4.4. Screen Tearing (by me) has also ocured on all others Linux Kernels from 3.8 up. I've tried 4.5 but, it's the same story.