# Diagonal Tearing (Kubuntu 16.04)

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, tearing

The question has been asked before here, but with no response: [Diagonal Screen Tearing Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751497/diagonal-screen-tearing-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-intel-skylake-integrated-graphics) (I'm asking again because I can't comment on it.)
The problem can be seen nicely in this video of someone with the same issue: https://youtu.be/qQTXr700nmE

I'm using an Nvidia GeForce GTX 675MX on the propriertary driver with dual monitors. I'm having the problem now in Kubuntu 16.04, but I've actually first seen it in several derivatives of Ubuntu 15.10. It seems to me like I've tried all the solutions commonly suggested for solving screen tearing. Is there anything I can to against this particular issue? Is it a problem within both the graphics drivers of Nvidia and Intel or is it something else?

Edit: My driver is nvidia-367, although I remember downgrading to 340 once with no luck.