# Diagonal graphic issue with Ubuntu 16.04...or malware?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, icons, screen

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786054/diagonal-tearing-kubuntu-16-04) I initially thought it might be a graphics card issue or a graphics driver issue, but since the issue happens only after waking from suspend and after restarting the computer the problem goes away, I'm considering this may be a problem with the way Ubuntu refreshes the screen or windows and icons. Or perhaps the Ubuntu updates screwing up some existing modules or maybe even a sign of malware infection or spyware (that takes screenshots).

This is Ubuntu 16.04 with latest updates installed and `lspci | grep VGA` showed `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)`.

**The issue (black rectangles in the image are added by me):**

[image]
[image]

I woke the computer from suspend, installed `gitg` and opened the `gitg` window to find these diagonal things appearing whenever I opened any window. It happened when I clicked any window, clicked "ok" on any dialog box, opened Nautilius or opened the System Monitor. Basically, any open or close of any window on the screen would make those weird diagonal things appear on screen. When they covered icons on the desktop and I moved the mouse pointer over the icons (without needing to click), the diagonal thing would remain as-is, but the rectangular area that makes up the icon space (including the icon) would appear clearly (meaning the screen wasn't being fully refreshed, but was being refreshed at the spot the icons are). After restarting the computer, this problem didn't show up again.

I've also noticed sometimes on waking from suspend, many of the icons in Unity aren't displayed. The rectangles that make up the icon space are there, but the icon isn't displayed. After restarting the computer, there's no such problem, but the diagonal thingy problem and a lot of flickering happened again after suspending and resuming from suspend and opening an application (it's not application-specific).

[image]

So is this a problem with the way Ubuntu refreshes the screen or something happenening due to Ubuntu updates messing up existing packages or signs that somebody could've installed some malware?

Comment: It is a problem with the embedded graphics of a crappy CPU that always had problems with Linux.

Comment: That's possible, since the laptop was shipped with Windows pre-installed, and being "Skype certified" (meaning their priorities were not anywhere close to supporting Linux). Intel Celeron processor N2840 with Intel HD graphics. Is there any site where such an issue has been documented (possibly the source of your info)?

Comment: My source is my own bad experiences with Bay Trail but a quick Google search will find you lots of results, some of them may contain suggestions for improving performance. But my comments are applicable to the CPU/GPU mentioned in the question, not the Celeron you mentioned now in comments. I had one miniPC of the same N28xx family and no complains (but I didn't test suspension because it was on most of the time as a media player and server and off when I was away from home).

Comment: The CPU/GPU I mentioned in my question is the same Celeron processor. I ran a JMonkey test program on it which showed the amount of CPU use and GPU use. The GPU was being used. I didn't even know this laptop had an inbuilt GPU. Since `lspci | grep VGA` shows an Intel Atom processor, perhaps this is the problem. Linux may have some optimizations or defaults for the old version of the processor it thinks it is or may have some new defaults for the new version, but my CPU is old.